# How to override preprocessed CSS element which is !important

Tags: css

The preprocessed css [/public_html/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Theme_custom/en_US/css] is overriding my custom css file because it have !important. It happens only on the large screens. How to fix it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out. In case anyone need it:

I created xml file:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_custom/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <css src="css/custom.css" media="screen and (min-width: 768px)"/>
  </head>
</page>
```

And css file:

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme_custom/web/css/custom.css

This overrides the preprocessed css

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the `.less` file that that is being compiled from, and either make the change there, or just remove the `!important`. Here are the Magento docs for that:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html

Comment: Read the question please, This css is located in pub/static. Its not a theme css, its preproccessed.

Comment: Right, I understand that. However, if it's being processed, it's coming from somewhere, and that's where the change would need to occur (if your goal was to remove the `!important`). Glad you figured it out!